# Question about spam site incorrectly deleted as spam

Tags: support, deleted-questions, spam

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/1737401) (deleted: link requires 10k+ reputation) was deleted as spam.

However, it's a question *about* spam. It contains some unfortunate language around this, but could surely be edited into shape by removing the spam keywords if those are seen as unwelcome.

Screen shot:

[image: Screen shot of deleted question]

To be perfectly candid, I posted an answer to this question (which is why I am able to view it, I expect) which I'm hoping would be useful for future visitors with the same question.

I looked for duplicates around this topic before answering. Perhaps the question might in some sense be more suitable for another site on the Stack Exchange network; but that is a separate discussion. *Deleting* it seems harsh, and deleting it as spam seems obviously wrong.

Comment: Hmmm, googling for the phrase returns https://hackforums.net/showthread.php?tid=6217532&action=lastpost which however requires me to sign up to view the thread, which I am unwilling to do. Perhaps this was plagiarized, and/or actually a spam seed.

Comment: It was a spam seed. an answer that was spam for "PDO threads Nasolabial folds" was less than 10 minutes after posting the question.

Comment: The website has also been spammed across the Internet for at least a couple of years https://www.google.com/search?&q=https%3A%2F%2Fdrcatalona.com%2Fbuy-xanax%2F in various subtle and unsubtle ways, I don't think we need to give them any legitimacy or credence.

Comment: @tripleee- “Deleting it seems harsh, and deleting it as spam seems obviously wrong.” **Except** it was spam seed, it received a spam answer, even if both of those things were not true it was out of scope and shouldn’t have been answered. Don’t answer questions that are out of scope. You cannot see the spam that was deleted.

Comment: I saw the spam before it was deleted, and I see a lot of deleted spam in Charcoal, where I am a regular and an admin. I'm not unhappy if the mods decided that it was spam, but since you brought it up again, I am still not entirely convinced that this was in fact a spam seed. I am aware that mods sometimes have additional information which us regular mortals can't access, but based on the evidence available to me, I still hesitate.

Comment: Charcoal's archived copy of the spam in question is at https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/382610 ... Perhaps notice also my comment at https://superuser.com/questions/1737401/%20/1737402#comment2690588_1737403 if you have the rep

Answer (score 1):

At an absolute minimum Websites and Web applications are explicitly [off topic here](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) except insofar as the problem is with your computer or browser. As such it should have been closed and deleted.

Whether a website has been hacked or spam like pages inserted is a question for the website owners. It might be intentional or it might be an "accident" or it could be that they were actually hacked.

It smelt like thinly veiled spam made to sound like a legitimate question.

Comment: It was a spam seed. an answer that was spam for "PDO threads Nasolabial folds" was less than 10 minutes after posting the question.

Comment: The spam post seemed unrelated, and the same domain was also spammed to an unrelated question on Stack Overflow around the same time. I think the spammer just used a tool which looks for (what the tool stupidly thinks are) posts about drugs, and spammed those.